# In Python, list certain type of file in a directory on Linux

Tags: linux, python-2.7

In my directory, there are a kind of type of file end in .log file. 
In ordinary, I use ls .*log commands to list all files.

However, I wanna to use Python code to handle with it. There are two ways I've tried.

First:

```
import subprocess

ls_al = subprocess.check_output(['ls','.*log'])
```

but it returns `ls: .*log: No such file or directory`

Second:

```
import subprocess

ls_al = subprocess.check_Popen(['ls','.*log'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

ls = ls_al.stdout.read().strip()
```

but those two didn't work.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I don't know if globbing works this way, but if it does, did you perhaps mean to say `['ls','*.log']`?

Answer (score 3):

Globbing patterns are expanded by the *shell*, but you are running the command *directly*. You'd have to run the command through the shell:

```
ls_al = subprocess.check_output('ls *.log', shell=True)
```

where you pass in the full command line to the shell as a string (and use the correct glob syntax).

Demo (using `*.py`):

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['ls', '*.py'])
ls: *.py: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ls', '*.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1
>>> subprocess.check_output('ls *.py', shell=True)
'calc.py\ndAll.py\nexample.py\ninplace.py\nmyTests.py\ntest.py\n'
```

Note that the correct way *in Python* is to use `os.listdir()` with manual filtering, filter with the `fnmatch` module, or use the [`glob` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to list and filter together:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('*.py')
['calc.py', 'dAll.py', 'example.py', 'inplace.py', 'myTests.py', 'test.py']
```

Answer (score 1):

`.*log` seems like regular expression, not globbing pattern. Do you mean `*.log`? (need `shell=True` argument to make shell do glob expansion)

BTW, [`glob.glob('*.log')`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) is more preferable way if you want list of file paths.

Comment: Using `*.log` won't work either, as it is the **shell** that does the glob expansion, not the `ls` command.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Ah.. I forgot `shell` parameter. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than run an external command, you could use Python's [os module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) to get the files in the directory.  Then the [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) can be used to create a regular expression to filter for your log files.  I think this would be a more pythonic approach.  It should also work on multiple platforms without modification. Note that in the code below I'm assuming your log files all end with '.log'; if you need something else you'll need to tinker with the regex.

```
import os
import re
import sys
the_dir = sys.argv[1]
all_files = os.listdir(the_dir)
log_files = []
log_pattern = re.compile('.*\.log')
for fn in all_files:
    if re.match(log_pattern, fn):
        log_files.append(fn)
print log_files
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob)?

```
$ ls
abc.txt bar.log def.txt foo.log ghi.txt zoo.log
$ python
>>> import glob
>>> for logfile in glob.glob('*.log'):
...     print(logfile)
...
bar.log
foo.log
zoo.log
>>>
```